# Android Market not showing full list of app updates

Tags: google-play-store, updates

When I have app updates, the android market notifies and takes me to the list of apps that have updates but some apps that have updates are not shown sometimes. Only when I go to search and key in the exact app name, the app shows up with its status showing there is indeed an update to it.

I hope you get my point. Why is this happening. Why doesn't the android market show all upgrades so that I can batch upgrade it?

I have around 135 apps Installed (as shown by Android Market 3.3.11)

Comment: Did you install those from backup or got them from *other* sources?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Both. I have apps that are installed out of the market and those from the market. Apps installed from the market itself has shown this problem.. though now after upgrading my rom and since play store came around, I feel this is no longer a problem to me..

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but still today I face the same issue. The reason behind this (AFAIK) is that apps, when updated, can be "batch updated" if no changes were made to the app privacy policy or the app permissions for the device *(other scenarios may apply)*.

**e.g.,**

Just this week I did a "batch update", but had to manually update two apps, one needed my consent for additional privileges, and the other one had changed something *that I didn't bothered to read*.

Message from the first app that was outside of the update batch:

> This app's permissions have changed to have access to the following: ...

*Due to this changes, this app was excluded from the batch update.*

Comment: I am aware of this one.. but that wasn't the problem. ie, the apps which 'had an update' didn't even appear in the "manual updates" list..

Comment: @Power-Inside That only leaves one thing, the developer did not provide a proper way to let the "OS" know about the new update.